# How to log thread pool metrics for Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, webclient, metrics

Is there a way to get thread pool metrics for logging (exporting) it to graphite dashboard for Spring WebClient.

There is a way to do a similar thing for Rest Template by configuring PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

```
 public Map<String, Metric> getMetrics() {
    final Map<String, Metric> gauges = new HashMap<>();

    for (Entry<String, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager> entry : connectionManagerMap
        .entrySet()) {
      gauges.put(entry.getKey() + ".leasedConnections",
          (Gauge<Integer>) () -> entry.getValue().getTotalStats().getLeased());
      gauges.put(entry.getKey() + ".maxConnections",
          (Gauge<Integer>) () -> entry.getValue().getTotalStats().getMax());
      gauges.put(entry.getKey() + ".pendingConnections",
          (Gauge<Integer>) () -> entry.getValue().getTotalStats().getPending());
      gauges.put(entry.getKey() + ".availableConnections",
          (Gauge<Integer>) () -> entry.getValue().getTotalStats().getAvailable());
    }

    return gauges;
  }
```

In the case of WebClient i am not sure how to get the HttpThreadPool, I created WebClient Object in the following way.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(downstream.getServiceLocation())
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .build();

**and clientHttpConnector was created:**

public ClientHttpConnector lbosClientHttpConnector() {
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> {
            options.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, applicationConfiguration.getDownstreams().getHttpClient().getSocketTimeout());
            options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, applicationConfiguration.getDownstreams().getHttpClient().getKeepAliveTimeoutInMs());
            options.poolResources(PoolResources.fixed("HTTP_CONNECTION_POOL", applicationConfiguration.getDownstreams().getHttpClient().getMaxConnections()));
        });
    }
```

Please provide a solution or guide me towards one.

Comment: how did you solve this? can you share sample code