# How to get PoolStats for WebClient for logging in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I converted the RestTemplate to WebClient in my Spring Boot 3 project. In RestTemplate we were using PoolStats for logging metrics of leased, pending, available, max stats. (Code below)

```
    private void printHttpClientStats(String qualifier, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager) {

        final PoolStats totalStats = httpClientConnectionManager.getTotalStats();
        log.info("HttpClient - {}: {}", qualifier, totalStats);
    }
```

However after switching to WebClient I couldn't be able to find how to get these info and log it the same way. How can I do this in WebClient?

I find this similar question but there are no answers to this one:
[How to log thread pool metrics for Spring WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113790/how-to-log-thread-pool-metrics-for-spring-webclient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to enable metrics in `ConnectionProvider`

```
ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                .maxConnections(maxConnTotal)
                .metrics(true)
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .build();
```

Then I was able to see logs from MeterRegistry object (repo)

```
Object[] meters = repo.getMeters().stream().filter(meter -> meter.getId().getName().contains("reactor")).toArray();
```

Reference:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_5